# Rectangle overlay on hovering a custom button

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to define a custom button style where on hover a rectangle pops up around that button.

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
@State private var isOverButton = false

func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {

    ZStack {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color("Frost1"))
    }
    .padding(3)
    .onHover { over in
        self.isOverButton = over
        print("isOverButton:", self.isOverButton, "over:", over)
    }
    .overlay(VStack {
        if self.isOverButton {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(Color("Frost1"), lineWidth: 2)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    })
}}
```

The print line shows me that setting the variable "isOverButton" is not working. Which type of variable state am I supposed to use that can be updated from "onHover" and updates "overlay"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestOnHoverButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button") {}
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    private struct CustomButtonStyleView<V: View>: View {
        @State private var isOverButton = false

        let content: () -> V

        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                content()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .padding(3)
            .onHover { over in
                self.isOverButton = over
                print("isOverButton:", self.isOverButton, "over:", over)
            }
            .overlay(VStack {
                if self.isOverButton {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        CustomButtonStyleView { configuration.label }
    }
}
```