# How to Create Custom SwiftUI Button Without Providing a Specific "Label" View?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, customization

I'm new to SwiftUI and there's something I cannot understand and I hope someone can explain this to me. Unfortunately, none of the SwiftUI tutorials I have read or watched or found have dived this deep into the fundamental concepts.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

> - I'm trying to create a bunch of SwiftUI buttons which are similar to each other in some aspects and different in some other aspects. So I'm
>   **NOT** looking for having ButtonA & ButtonB & ButtonC & ... and configure each of them separately. The ideal solution is to have a
>   GeneralButton to which I can pass multiple parameters and configure it
>   to the specific need of that instance.
> - I have several presets for those buttons so I'm trying to create some sort of styling mechanism in which I can create a button using
>   one of those predefined styles.

The approach I'm trying:

> - I'm trying to create a custom `ButtonStyle` that has a property which contains the type of style I need and configure the button based
>   on that.
> - I also am trying to put all the required subviews (Which are not a lot) in the body of that general button and configure them based on
>   the type of button (e.g in an icon-only button the icon is the only
>   element in the button, there's no title, subtitle, indicator, etc)

**The issue:**

> - I cannot access the custom body of the button from the `makeBody` function in the ButtonStyle protocol and hence I cannot do any
>   customisation over subviews.

**The ambiguous part:**

> - I checked  the properties on `ButtonStyleConfiguration` in order to find out how
>   can I access the view's body, and saw that not only the body is not
>   accessible, there is a Label property existing there statically. While
>   it was weird to have a label there (Because a button does not
>   necessarily needs a label! Yes it usually does but not always) Since
>   it was a SwiftUI view I tried to cast it to the kind of view I'm
>   trying for which I faced the following error: `Cast from 'ButtonStyleConfiguration.Label' to unrelated type '[MyButtonPrefix]Button' always fails`
> - I went a bit deeper and read the documentation for SwiftUI Button struct in general, and as can be seen below, it is designed to have a
>   "Label" and if that cannot be inferred from the subviews it won't let
>   you create the button:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct Button<Label> : View where Label : View {

    /// Creates a button that displays a custom label.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - action: The action to perform when the user triggers the button.
    ///   - label: A view that describes the purpose of the button's `action`.
    public init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)

    /// The content and behavior of the view.
    public var body: some View { get }

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body = some View
}
```

The document explicitly dictates the necessity of having the Label and the nature of SwiftUI's button being designed to show a label :

> Creates a button that displays a custom label

**I'm pretty sure that I'm making some serious mistake as I'm absolutely new to SwiftUI but I can't understand what's going on above and any explanation is really appreciated.
All the tutorials I have went through were treating SwiftUI's Button as something that obviously has a "Label" and I haven't found anything that has provided a more general and modular perspective on creating completely custom and fully reusable button-related components in SwiftUI.**

Comment: Without knowing more about exactly what you want your button to do, it's hard to say if this would work. But I would try to shift from thinking about implementing a button to implementing a view that contains a button.  That way you can pass in whatever you want to the view with no restrictions and use it to customize  the button behavior.  Think 
struct MyCustomButton: View {
  var name: String
  var body: some View {
     Button(name) {
       //doSomethingHere
 }
}

Comment: @NicholasRees Thank you for the idea, but then how should I handle the state changes and taps and Button-Specific kind of stuff?

Comment: State changes: passing in a \@State variable using \@Binding.  Button specific stuff: if statements inside the button action?  But i'll back up a step and get on my personal hobby-horse: you should probably write the code as separate buttons first. When I do this, I usually find the thing I *thought* should be a centralized library actually isn't.  The chances that are pretty low that, as a new-to-the-language developer, you are going to write a good reusable library before you've figured out the idiomatic way to use existing libraries

Comment: ButtonStyle allows to use inside other views. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655372/12299030? (or same as that one)